# How to secure an AWS Lambda function so it can only be called from a CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

The [Using Amazon CloudFront with AWS Lambda as origin to accelerate your web applications | Networking & Content Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-aws-lambda-as-origin-to-accelerate-your-web-applications/) post the explains how to setup a CloudFront distribution with a Lambda Function URL origin.

The blog says to create the function url with auth NONE but if you want to ensure requests are routed through CloudFront you can assign a static secret header.

This option doesn't seem great, because it's a static secret and because anyone will be able to invoke the Lambda (though they will get a 401 error).

> Under ‘Advanced settings’, check the ‘Enable function URL’ field. Since the Lambda function needs to be publicly accessible select ‘NONE’ for Auth type. This also create the necessary resource based policies to allow public access to the function.
>
> As part of your origin configuration, you could set a static secret header which CloudFront inserts before making requests to your origin. This allows you to validate the presence of the header and value in your Lambda Function and ensure that requests are being routed through CloudFront.

Is there a way for my distribution to authenticate to Lambda with AWS_IAM, or to put the Lambda in a VPC that only my distribution can call?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way at the moment is to:

1. Create a Lambda@Edge function to sign each request with Sigv4 before it reaches the origin (Lambda Function URL)
2. Give the Lambda@Egde function permission to invoke the target Lambda function.
3. Set the Lambda@Edge function as the 'Origin Request' function of your CloudFront distribution

Lambda@Edge Function - Example:

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth
from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest
import urllib
import base64

session = boto3.Session()
CREDENTIALS = session.get_credentials()
creds = CREDENTIALS.get_frozen_credentials()

def signed_request(request):
    '''Sign AWS API request headers'''
    headers = request['headers']
    url = f"https://{headers['host'][0]['value']}{request['uri']}"
    method = request['method']
    # We need to sign the body too
    data = base64.b64decode(request['body']['data'])
    # Next line flattens the AWS headers format to python 'requests' one
    headers = {v[0]['key']:v[0]['value'] for k,v in headers.items()}
    # This header should not be signed as it changes hop to hop
    headers.pop('X-Forwarded-For')
    # Grab the region from the lambda function URL, ex: kjh123kjhbrkj.lambda-url.eu-west-2.on.aws
    url_segments = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).netloc.split('.')
    region = url_segments[2]
    req = AWSRequest(method=method, url=url, params=None, headers=headers, data=data)
    SigV4Auth(creds, 'lambda', region).add_auth(req)
    signed_headers=dict(req.headers.items())
    # format the headers for Cloudfront, ex:
    # "headers": {
    #   "user-agent": [
    #     {
    #       "key": "User-Agent",
    #       "value": "Amazon CloudFront"
    #     }
    #   ]
    # }
    request['headers'] = { k.lower():[{'key':k,'value':v}] for k,v in signed_headers.items() }
    
    return request

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    return signed_request(request)

def main():
    # main function is used for local debugging only
    with open("templates/cf_request_test.json", "r") as f:
        event = json.load(f)
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    request = signed_request(request)
    import requests
    headers = request['headers']
    data = base64.b64decode(request['body']['data'])
    print(data)
    url = f"https://{headers['host'][0]['value']}{request['uri']}"
    method = request['method']
    headers = {v[0]['key']:v[0]['value'] for k,v in headers.items()}
    response = requests.request(method=method, url=url, headers=headers, data=data)

    print(response.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) in front of the lambda and use an API key in your call.

Comment: I'm hoping for an option that skips API Gateway, for cost and complexity reasons. Is an API key any different than the solution from the blog post to use a shared secret header?

Comment: Maybe this will help if you haven't looked at already https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html